# How to save a serializable object using File.WriteAllBytes?, C#

Tags: c#, serialization, save

I need to save an object, its serializable but I donot want to use XML.
Is it possible to write the raw bytes of the object and then read it off the disk to create the object again?

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is called binary serialization.  There are some good examples on the MSDN site:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4abbf6k0(v=vs.100).aspx

Answer (score 2):

Use a [`BinaryFormatter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.formatters.binary.binaryformatter.aspx):

```
var formatter = new BinaryFormatter();

// Serialize
using (var stream = File.OpenWrite(path))
{
    formatter.Serialize(stream, yourObject);
}

...

// Deserialize
using (var stream = File.OpenRead(path))
{
    YourType yourObject = (YourType)formatter.Deserialize(stream);
}
```

Comment: but for passing objects between projects, both of them need to reside in a common assembly/namespace